# How to pass js variable into hidden form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass js variable into hidden form field value. I set value using php echo code but it is not working.

js variable :-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var demo = 1; </script>
```

html :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="demo_val" value="<?php echo <script>demo</script>" id="demo_val"/>
```

and in js file call hidden field value :-

```
$('#demo_val').val();
```

but it is not working...

How to do it..?

Comment: What is this `value="<?php echo <script>demo</script>"` suppose to be?

Comment: try to pass value in hidden form field

Comment: want to pass demo variable value pass using hidden form field...

Comment: use ajax request on success pass the value to hidden input

Comment: First, this code is wrong, you dont close the php tag. Second, you can't pass js variable using php without using ajax request.

Comment: [You must escape the `<script>` tag in the value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). this might be vulnerable code. also, `<?php echo <script>demo</script>" id...` is not valid. `<?php echo '<script>demo</script>; ?>" id...` is one of the right (but still not safest) way(s) to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this `<?php echo <script>demo</script>` from hidden field and leave it blank.

Write followed code

```
var demo =1;
$('#demo_val').val(demo);
```

in your script. 
You can get value by

```
var field_vemo = $('#demo_val').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="demo_val" value="" id="demo_val"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var demo = 1; 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#demo_val').val(demo);
});
</script>
```

Comment: you are trying to echo js variable throw php. it is not possible this way. you can use AJAX if you want. also you already have js variable here <script type="text/javascript"> var demo = 1; </script>

Comment: `$(#demo_val).val(demo);` should be `$('#demo_val').val(demo);`. The difference is the quotes around `#demo_val`

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
document.getElementById("demo_val").value = demo;
```

in your javascript section

Comment: First i want to set value in hidden form field....this answer is not sufficient...

Comment: @RHapani : Actually this is sufficient, since it sets the value in form field

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the variable since javascript yo input hidden, not it´s good idea pass the variable with  , you can use jQuery :

```
var demo = "hola";
$('#demo_val').val(demo);
```

Now input with name demo_val should have the value "hola"

If you like get the value you can

```
var valueDemo = $('#demo_val').val();
```